# How can bind property block monotouch

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I'm learning how to bind objective c to monotouch and I'm having trouble with a property that is a block

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onLongPress)(UIView*, NSInteger);
```

I have this at the moment

```
delegate void onLongPress (UIView view, int index);
[Export ("onLongPress")]
void onLongPress() {  set;  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation on how to bind blocks is there http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries at 3.10

But your code shows a block property, not a function taking a property.

In your case, I would bind it like this:

```
//ApiDefinition.cs
delegate void OnLongPress (UIView view, int index)

[Export("onLongPress")]
OnLongPress OnLongPress { set;}
```

This will probably works, but as I've never encountered that particular case, I'm interested in your results.